# Calling a Javascript function from ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My code is:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() {
        alert("Hello");
    }
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="change"/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

The error I get is:
CS1061: 'ASP.webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'change' and no extension method 'change' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webform1_aspx' could be found.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3):-

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return change();"/>
```

`OnClick` event is used to bind server side method on button click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() {
        alert("Hello");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Not that the `return false` will stop the postback cause by the button.
And for this you should also mention `return` before your function call on button like `OnClientClick="return change();"`

Answer (score 3):

It should be `OnClientClick`:-

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="change"/>
```

`OnClick` event is used to bind server side method on button click.

Answer (score 1):

`OnClick="change"` it means that you should Create Method name as `change` on server Side

Some thing like this

```
protected void change(object sender,EventArgs e)
{

}
```

On Server Side

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick","change();")
}
```

on .aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```